# Is there a way to auto install anything I need in a new linux distribution with one file?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I know the question is very poorly redacted, I couldn't find the words to do it, let me explain. What I want is to make a file (I imagine this can be done with a text file but I have very little knowledge of coding and linux in general) that contains all of the instalation command lines of any program I want, and then to be able to run that file in any new distro so that I have everything I need by just runnning that one line and having the file.

I know that the instalation line will have to change depending on the distribution, the question aims to the how to create (or it its possible to) the file that would be run.

Any help is apprecieated.

Comment: Maybe overkill for your needs, but [Ansible](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/manage-workstation-ansible) is widely used for configuration management.

Comment: you could look at FAI maybe it does what you want, but it runs during install, not after. https://fai-project.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with a Bash script. In fact, I and a few others I know all use our own bash scripts to install everything we need after booting into a fresh install. Here are the first lines from my installation.sh for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install mplayer tmux irssi emacs openssh-server nmap lynx links surf i3 i3status htop feh filezilla mpv palemoon thunderbird steam audacious audacious-plugins qbittorrent atril wireshark pan gimp audacity virtualbox virtualbox-guest-additions-iso bmon ncdu ncmpc qpdfview lxqt icewm
```

A few things to note: This is made for Debian-based distros that make use of the apt-get frontend, but it can be tweaked to use another distro's frontend with ease. `install` can take multiple programs at a time, but if you have 1 of them spelled wrong, it will error out. Test it in a VM or similar testing environment to make sure it doesn't error out. If you use flatpaks or snaps, the CLI frontends for those can be included too. Please read the manual pages for your preferred installation commands to ensure you're using the correct syntax and parameters.

You will also need to run `chmod a+x $scriptName` (for all users) or `chmod u+x $scriptName` (for the file's owner, presumably you) when you're done. This marks it as executable. Without it, you can't run the script.

This will get you started, but I highly recommend watching a bash scripting tutorial, as it is a powerful language that will allow you to automate all kinds of tasks. If you find bash isn't the best for the job, try out a different shell and learn that instead.

Comment: Added. Yes, which requires me to update my command since the package names are hardcoded in.

Comment: I do something similar except using multiple lines with only 4 or 5 apps per line. You then have to say y to each line, but it forces me to watch install & see if any of the app lines fail.

Comment: Thanks, yes this is just what I was thinking!